# asp:changePassword cellpadding

Tags: asp.net, css, change-password

So im using the asp:changePassword which shows the form which allows the user to display the password;
I'm then centering the panel on screen. However I would like to add spacing/cell padding between the rows:
So far I have :

```
<div style="position:relative;left:300px;top:100px;padding:10px;">
       <asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword2" CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">

       </asp:ChangePassword>
    </div>
```

I've tried:
TextBoxStyle-CssClass & BorderPadding and tried positioning the div inside the changePassword and using 'class' to center it.

i see there is a  and then create table and rows etc...

Is there a simpler way to do this? All i want to do is seperate each row in the changePassword Panel by 'cellpadding =5px'

Please advise thank you

EDIT:

```
<div style="position:relative;left:300px;top:100px;padding:10px;">      
            <asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
               <asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword2" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                BorderWidth="1px" CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">             
                </asp:ChangePassword>
           </asp:GridView>       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be using the GridView control. Then in the markup, be sure to set cellpadding and cellspacing to zero and then apply the following CSS...

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table tr, table td, table th { border: solid 5px #000; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: @Rachel_Gallen Thanks but it wont allow me to put the asp:changePassword inside the asp:gridview ad vise versa..,i've added the code as an edit of my original message

Comment: so you took my advice about the gridview anyway? that should be worth an upvote?... :)

Comment: Hey Rach...(please see my previous comment) it doesnt allow me to put changePassword inside the gridView, so need to change it...ay ideas?

Comment: oh i thought you'd solved it - have you got your gridview editable = true?

Comment: see  here for datagrid code samples http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0 Also see this link re password changing: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2011/02/13/access-controls-with-in-change-password-control.aspx

Comment: I tried setting the editable= true but there is no option for it, so tried EditRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"./..the errors I am getting are: </asp:changePassword> doesnt match any properties within a gridview, make sure its well formatted, ALSO gridview doesnt have a public property named 'changePassword;'

Comment: see the second link in my previous comment

Comment: Thanks for that link, but isnt the asp:changePassword like a concrete panel that cant be played about with? so would puttin it iside a gridview really help? Please advise ta

Comment: i think i found an interesting answer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367725/asp-net-encrypted-membership-password-username-retrieval